# Began bicycling cardio program a couple of weeks ago, and am still really tired all day. Is this normal?

Tags: cardio, bicycling, tiredness

I've restarted an exercise program, after a couple of years of not doing too much.  I'm not particularly out of shape (45 yo, 5'10, 180 lbs), and can get through my program just fine, but I end up rather tired for a lot of the day - to the point where it's hard to get other stuff done.  I've been biking 10-11 miles a day, at a little over 11 mph.  It's a rather hilly route, and according to my fitbit, I'm hitting about 8 minutes of fat-burn, 40 minutes of cardio and 10 minutes of peak heart-rate, and burning about 680 calories.

My question is this - is it normal that after a couple of weeks of doing this 6-days a week, that I should still feel zonked for a few hours after my work-out?  How long until I can do this kind of program and recover relatively quickly?  Are there tricks (nutrition, warm-ups, etc.) that can reduce the recovery time?

Comment: What's your eating like? Tracking calories and protein at all?

Comment: Eating is pretty normal, I think.  Low carb (for an American, at least) but not really low.  Fried egg for breakfast, lunch of fruits, veggies, deli meat, hummus, etc.  Dinners may be bun-less burgers with roasted potatoes and salad, an indian curry with cauliflower rice, yogurt and vegetable, etc.  Occasional snacks (cookie, crackers & cheese, etc.)  I'm not tracking calories, but am not hungry.

Comment: My first instinct is that you're over-training and ramped up too fast/too far. My first experiment would be to dial back both intensity (distance and/or speed) and frequency (e.g., every other day) and see what happens over ~2 wks.

Comment: You might not be hungry, but since you are burning more calories you might need more calories coming in as well. I can recommend protein shakes with some quick-digesting carbs immediately after working out to re-feed the body.